# SSRS 2008 SUM using scope and recursive option to rollup values

Tags: sql-server, recursion, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Consider this data (6 rows and 1 column for now)

```
;with cols as
(
 SELECT 1 colID, 'C1' col
 --UNION SELECT 2, 'C2' 
)
, rows as
(
 SELECT 1 RowID, 'R1' row, null ParentID
 UNION SELECT 2, 'R2', 1
 UNION SELECT 3, 'R3', 2 
 UNION SELECT 4, 'R4', 2 
 UNION SELECT 5, 'R5', 1 
 UNION SELECT 6, 'R6', 1 
)
,data
AS
(
 SELECT 3 RowID, 1 as Amount
 UNION SELECT 4 RowID, 2 as Amount
)
SELECT r.RowID, r.row, c.colID, c.col, d.Amount, r.ParentID
FROM rows r 
CROSS JOIN cols c
LEFT JOIN data d on d.RowID = r.RowID
```

[image]

I apply this to a matrix control using the following layout and get the output as shown.  Notice how the amounts are not rolled up to the parent rows. THis is ok for now.

[image]

Now, to get the values to roll up I can use the expression (well documented by msdn, blogs, etc)

```
=Sum(Fields!Amount.Value, "RowGroup", recursive)
```

This now gives me exactly what I want, with the values rolling up to their parent rows:

[image]

However, my dataset has dynamic column as well as rows but when a second (or third, forth, etc) column is introduced the recursive sum doesn't work as I expect.  Instead of staying within the scope of the current column it sums all the columns and then rolls those values up to the parent lines.  as shown:

[image]

I want the values to only get rolled up within the current scope of a given row and column.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated as this has stumped me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This isn't actually possible due to needing to look at both the row group scope and the column group scope..

I spent a long time searching for an answer.. For anyone else looking. here are some better explanations from other forums:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/55c55aad-4755-4da5-afce-94d16c9e201d/cannot-perform-a-correct-recursive-sum-in-a-tablix?forum=sqlreportingservices

> Unfortunately, the scenario you described is not supported so far (both 2008 and 2005), because it cannot do Recursive sum in two scopes in a matrix. If you replace the expression with SUM(Fields!Amount.Value, "NAME", Recursive), you will get the recursive total, but the tota willl ignore the monthindex group. Actually, you want to recursive sum for both groups NAME and MonthIndex, however you cannot write expression like this: SUM(Fields!Amount.Value, "NAME" and MonthIndex, Recursive). Right? So generally speaking, in a matrix, when you write the expression like this: SUM(Fields!Amount.Value) It will sum in the scope of two groupsNAME and MonthIndex, and if you want to specify the scope, you have to specify only one scope. And unfortunately, the recursive sum needs to specify the scope and scenario you described needs to specify two scopes

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9d7f36bc-73d6-4f19-a306-0b84321e6feb/calculating-the-sum-on-a-hierarchy-with-multiple-grouping-columns?forum=sqlreportingservices